# What does 'items[i].label' do in my code?

Tags: javascript

What does `items[i].label;` do in my code? it is not working without it. I dont get why label is needed.
What my code does: It alerts selected item from a Jqlistbox.

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#jqxWidget').on('click', function () {

    var items = $("#jqxWidget").jqxListBox("getSelectedItems");
    if (items.length > 0) {
      var lstItem="";
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
        lstItem += items[i].label; //what does this label? 
      }
      alert(lstItem);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You are concatenating the `label` property for each item in `items` to `lstItem`. Without that line `lstItem` would be an empty string.

Comment: Also `it is not working` is not a problem description. What isn't working? Does it give you errors? What errors? Does it do something unexpected? What does it do? What did you expect it to do? Write better problem descriptions and you'll find you get better answers (because people don't have to guess what you mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `var items = $("#jqxWidget").jqxListBox("getSelectedItems");` from their API says:

> Gets the selected ListBox items. The returned value is an Array of
>   items.
>
> Each item represents an Object with the following fields.  Item Fields
>
> - label - gets item's label.
> - value - gets the item's value.
> - disabled - gets whether the item is enabled/disabled.
> - checked - gets whether the item is checked/unchecked.
> - hasThreeStates - determines whether the item's checkbox supports three states.
> - html - gets the item's display html. This can be used instead of label.
> - index - gets the item's index.
> - group - gets the item's group.

So that sets the value of the `items` variable with an array of selected items. Arrays are used to store multiple values in a single variable. To access those values you need to use an index.

This line: `for (var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {` says initialize the variable `i` with the value 0. While `i` is less than the length (or size of my array) continue looping and for each loop add 1 to `i` until the previous condition fails.

Lastly, the line you ask about `lstItem += items[i].label;` says during each loop take our index, `i` and access a value on the object, the value being `label` which was defined above in their API as a property on each object in the array of objects returned by `getSelectedItems`. So if our array has 3 objects in it this for loop will do this 3 times:

```
lstItem += items[0].label;  // First iteration i = 0
lstItem += items[1].label;  // Second iteration i = 1
lstItem += items[2].label;  // Third iteration i = 2
```

Adding the value of label to `lstItem` each time. After the third loop `i` will have the value 3 and since 3 is not less than 3 the for loop stops looping.

You need label because the array has objects as values. These objects look like this:

```
var example = {
    label: 'somevalue',
    value: 'somevalue',
    disabled: 'somevalue',
    checked: 'somevalue',
    hasThreeStates: 'somevalue',
    html: 'somevalue',
    index: 'somevalue',
    group: 'somevalue'
};
```

So since the items[i] would return an object like that to access that property you need to do `example.label`. So `items[i].label` gets you the index of the value of `i` and accesses the label property on that object.

Answer (score 1):

It gives the value of the label key within your items object.

Answer (score 1):

It gives you the value of your items object (your object is named items)